# I tried answering this question but my answer is in decimal. How can a number of muffin be in decimal?

Tags: fractions, percentages

Mrs Ho baked a total of 60 banana muffins and chocolate muffins. After she gave away 5/7 of the banana muffins and 1/2 of the chocolate muffins, she had twice as many as chocolate muffins as banana muffins left. She then baked another 12 banana muffins and 14 chocolate muffins. How many banana muffins did she have in the end?

I tried answering this question but my answer is in decimal. How can a number of muffin be in decimal? Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please show your attempt.  I suppose it's possible to have a fraction of a muffin, but I got $\mathbf{40}$

Comment: We can't find what went wrong unless we see your work.  How many muffins of each type were in the original batch?

Comment: You can have a decimal number of muffins, like bite off $1/4$ and then you have $0.75$ muffins... but I doubt that is what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

After she gives away $\frac{5}{7}$ of her banana muffins, she has$\frac{2}{7}$ of here banana muffins left. When she gives away $\frac{1}{2}$ of her chocolate muffins, she has $\frac{1}{2}$ of her chocolate muffins left.

She also has twice as many chocolate muffins left, as banana muffins left. This means $\frac{4}{7}B=\frac{1}{2}C$ .Which, means  $\frac{7+8}{7}B=\frac{15}{7}B=60$ . Dividing on both sides by 15 we get$\frac{1}{7}B=4$. This implies B is 28, by multiplicication by 7.

Using our earlier facts, we get she had $\frac{6}{7}B=24$ muffins left. She then makes $12+14=26$ more. Leaving her with 50.